# Connect to WPF c# application remote SQL database

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, database, wpf

I have my c# WPF application and SQL database (created with phpmyadmin) on remote server. How could I connect to my remote database straight from my WPF app? I 've tried to connect by connectionstring in app.config file, but smth goes wrong (TCP provider error 0 force closing connection).

Comment: Not all ISP allows your app to connect to at their online database remotely. In particular the ones that give you a free sql account and db

Comment: I completely agree with you, but there's no problem.

Comment: What kind of DB is it (MySQL or SQL server)? Did you try to connect to it with some other client?

Comment: MySql DB. I've just solved the problem. Thank you for your attention. The matter was in appropriate Provider Reference and AccessRules on the remote server.

Answer (score 0):

I've just solved the problem. Thank you for your attention. The matter was in appropriate Provider Reference and AccessRules on the remote server.